# Can I speed up this aerodynamics calculation with Numba, vectorization, or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multiprocessing, numba

## Problem:

I am trying to increase the speed of an aerodynamics function in Python.

### Function Set:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

def calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices(
    points, origins, terminations, strengths, collapse=True
):

    # Expand the dimensionality of the points input. It is now of shape (N x 1 x 3).
    # This will allow NumPy to broadcast the upcoming subtractions.
    points = np.expand_dims(points, axis=1)
    
    # Define the vectors from the vortex to the points. r_1 and r_2 now both are of
    # shape (N x M x 3). Each row/column pair holds the vector associated with each
    # point/vortex pair.
    r_1 = points - origins
    r_2 = points - terminations
    
    r_0 = r_1 - r_2
    r_1_cross_r_2 = nb_2d_explicit_cross(r_1, r_2)
    r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude = (
        r_1_cross_r_2[:, :, 0] ** 2
        + r_1_cross_r_2[:, :, 1] ** 2
        + r_1_cross_r_2[:, :, 2] ** 2
    )
    r_1_length = nb_2d_explicit_norm(r_1)
    r_2_length = nb_2d_explicit_norm(r_2)
    
    # Define the radius of the line vortices. This is used to get rid of any
    # singularities.
    radius = 3.0e-16
    
    # Set the lengths and the absolute magnitudes to zero, at the places where the
    # lengths and absolute magnitudes are less than the vortex radius.
    r_1_length[r_1_length < radius] = 0
    r_2_length[r_2_length < radius] = 0
    r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude[r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude < radius] = 0
    
    # Calculate the vector dot products.
    r_0_dot_r_1 = np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ij", r_0, r_1)
    r_0_dot_r_2 = np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ij", r_0, r_2)
    
    # Calculate k and then the induced velocity, ignoring any divide-by-zero or nan
    # errors. k is of shape (N x M)
    with np.errstate(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore"):
        k = (
            strengths
            / (4 * np.pi * r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude)
            * (r_0_dot_r_1 / r_1_length - r_0_dot_r_2 / r_2_length)
        )
    
        # Set the shape of k to be (N x M x 1) to support numpy broadcasting in the
        # subsequent multiplication.
        k = np.expand_dims(k, axis=2)
    
        induced_velocities = k * r_1_cross_r_2
    
    # Set the values of the induced velocity to zero where there are singularities.
    induced_velocities[np.isinf(induced_velocities)] = 0
    induced_velocities[np.isnan(induced_velocities)] = 0

    if collapse:
        induced_velocities = np.sum(induced_velocities, axis=1)

    return induced_velocities


@njit    
def nb_2d_explicit_norm(vectors):
    return np.sqrt(
        (vectors[:, :, 0]) ** 2 + (vectors[:, :, 1]) ** 2 + (vectors[:, :, 2]) ** 2
    )


@njit
def nb_2d_explicit_cross(a, b):
    e = np.zeros_like(a)
    e[:, :, 0] = a[:, :, 1] * b[:, :, 2] - a[:, :, 2] * b[:, :, 1]
    e[:, :, 1] = a[:, :, 2] * b[:, :, 0] - a[:, :, 0] * b[:, :, 2]
    e[:, :, 2] = a[:, :, 0] * b[:, :, 1] - a[:, :, 1] * b[:, :, 0]
    return e
```

## Context:

This function is used by [Ptera Software](https://github.com/camUrban/PteraSoftware), an open-source solver for flapping wing aerodynamics. As shown by the profile output below, it is by far the largest contributor to Ptera Software's run time.

[image: profile run]

Currently, Ptera Software takes just over 3 minutes to run a typical case, and my goal is to get this below 1 minute.

The function takes in a group of points, origins, terminations, and strengths. At every point, it finds the induced velocity due to the line vortices, which are characterized by the groups of origins, terminations, and strengths. If collapse is true, then the output is the cumulative velocity induced at each point due to the vortices. If false, the function outputs each vortex's contribution to the velocity at each point.

During a typical run, the velocity function is called approximately 2000 times. At first, the calls involve vectors with relatively small input arguments (around 200 points, origins, terminations, and strengths). Later calls involve large input arguments (around 400 points and around 6,000 origins, terminations, and strengths). An ideal solution would be fast for all size inputs, but increasing the speed of large input calls is more important.

For testing, I recommend running the following script with your own implementation of the function:

```
import timeit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_repeat = 2
n_execute = 10 ** 3
min_oom = 0
max_oom = 3

times_py = []

for i in range(max_oom - min_oom + 1):
    n_elem = 10 ** i
    n_elem_pretty = np.format_float_scientific(n_elem, 0)
    print("Number of elements: " + n_elem_pretty)

    # Benchmark Python.
    print("\tBenchmarking Python...")
    setup = '''
import numpy as np

these_points = np.random.random((''' + str(n_elem) + ''', 3))
these_origins = np.random.random((''' + str(n_elem) + ''', 3))
these_terminations = np.random.random((''' + str(n_elem) + ''', 3))
these_strengths = np.random.random(''' + str(n_elem) + ''')

def calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices(points, origins, terminations,
                                                strengths, collapse=True):
    pass
    '''
    statement = '''
results_orig = calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices(these_points, these_origins,
                                                           these_terminations,
                                                           these_strengths)
    '''
    
    times = timeit.repeat(repeat=n_repeat, stmt=statement, setup=setup, number=n_execute)
    time_py = min(times)/n_execute
    time_py_pretty = np.format_float_scientific(time_py, 2)
    print("\t\tAverage Time per Loop: " + time_py_pretty + " s")

    # Record the times.
    times_py.append(time_py)

sizes = [10 ** i for i in range(max_oom - min_oom + 1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(sizes, times_py, label='Python')
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_xlabel("Size of List or Array (elements)")
ax.set_ylabel("Average Time per Loop (s)")
ax.set_title(
    "Comparison of Different Optimization Methods\nBest of "
    + str(n_repeat)
    + " Runs, each with "
    + str(n_execute)
    + " Loops"
)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

## Previous Attempts:

My prior attempts at speeding up this function involved vectorizing it (which worked great, so I kept those changes) and trying out Numba's JIT compiler. I had mixed results with Numba. When I tried to use Numba on a modified version of the entire velocity function, my results were much slower than before. However, I found that Numba significantly sped up the cross-product and norm functions, which I implemented above.

## Updates:

### Update 1:

Based on Mercury's comment (which has since been deleted), I replaced

```
points = np.expand_dims(points, axis=1)
r_1 = points - origins
r_2 = points - terminations
```

with two calls to the following function:

```
@njit
def subtract(a, b):
    c = np.empty((a.shape[0], b.shape[0], 3))
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b.shape[0]):
            for k in range(3):
                c[i, j, k] = a[i, k] - b[j, k]
    return c
```

This resulted in a speed increase from 227 s to 220 s. This is better! However, it is still not fast enough.

I also have tried setting the njit fastmath flag to true, and using a numba function instead of calls to np.einsum. Neither increased the speed.

### Update 2:

With Jérôme Richard's answer, the run time is now 156 s, which is a decrease of 29%! I'm satisfied enough to accept this answer, but feel free to make other suggestions if you think you can improve on their work!

Comment: Excellent work vectorizing what you did. It looks good. I'm not a numba expert, but in some cases, I think numba can work *better* on non-vectorized code. As painful as it may be, it could be worth reverting back to for-loops in plain python with numba to see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, @PaulH! When I tried "numba-ing" the entire function, I used a bunch of nested for-loops. Unfortunately, the code was still much slower. However, I was still using several numpy functions. Do you think that those could have caused the slowdown?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Looking briefly at the repo, it seems like you call this function 3 times sequentially, have you looked into parallelising those calls itself, i.e. running them in separate threads/processes?
https://github.com/camUrban/PteraSoftware/blob/5cce0e1c819e89e947ca4f29699ac8c0cabd2e4e/pterasoftware/aerodynamics.py#L801

Comment: @wingedNorthropi note that the first call to Numba functions are very slow as the code must be compiled. However, you can put the compiled code in a cache to mitigate the cost. Alternatively you can provide the types to the Numba functions so that the compilation can be done ahead of time. Finally, Numba can sometimes vectorize the code less efficiently than native precompiled Numpy calls.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, as pointed out by @Adehad, I often call `calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices` three or four times in immediate succession. Actually, this is true almost every time. With your answer, would it make sense to use multiprocessing or Numba to parallelize these calls? If so, how would recommend I go about this? For example, should I use multiprocessing's `starmap` feature, or should I just use Numba?

Comment: @wingedNorthropi the answer already use multiple (Numba) threads so multiprocessing will not help your program to be faster (at least not for this function). The proposed solution is still *highly memory bound*. SO I think the only way to further improve the code on common CPUs is to factorize the code so that things are computed on the fly.

Comment: You can have more information about the impact of being mostly memory bound [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model) and contextual information [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Numba can perform **parallel computations** resulting in a faster code if you manually request it using mainly `parallel=True` and `prange`. This is useful for big arrays (but not for small ones).

Moreover, your computation is mainly **memory bound**. Thus, you should avoid creating big arrays when they are not reused multiple times, or more generally when they cannot be recomputed on the fly (in a relatively cheap way). This is the case for `r_0` for example.

In addition, **memory access pattern** matters: vectorization is more efficient when accesses are **contiguous** in memory and the cache/RAM is use more efficiently. Consequently, `arr[0, :, :] = 0` should be faster then `arr[:, :, 0] = 0`. Similarly, `arr[:, :, 0] = arr[:, :, 1] = 0` should be mush slower than `arr[:, :, 0:2] = 0` since the former performs to noncontinuous memory passes while the latter performs only one more contiguous memory pass. Sometimes, it can be beneficial to *transpose* your data so that the following calculations are much faster.

Moreover, Numpy tends to create many **temporary arrays** that are costly to allocate. This is a huge problem when the input arrays are small. The Numba jit can avoid that in most cases.

Finally, regarding your computation, it may be a good idea to use **GPUs** for big arrays (definitively not for small ones). You can give a look to **cupy** or **clpy** to do that quite easily.

Here is an optimized implementation working on the CPU:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def subtract(a, b):
    c = np.empty((a.shape[0], b.shape[0], 3))
    for i in prange(c.shape[0]):
        for j in range(c.shape[1]):
            for k in range(3):
                c[i, j, k] = a[i, k] - b[j, k]
    return c

@njit(parallel=True)
def nb_2d_explicit_norm(vectors):
    res = np.empty((vectors.shape[0], vectors.shape[1]))
    for i in prange(res.shape[0]):
        for j in range(res.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = np.sqrt(vectors[i, j, 0] ** 2 + vectors[i, j, 1] ** 2 + vectors[i, j, 2] ** 2)
    return res

# NOTE: better memory access pattern
@njit(parallel=True)
def nb_2d_explicit_cross(a, b):
    e = np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in prange(e.shape[0]):
        for j in range(e.shape[1]):
            e[i, j, 0] = a[i, j, 1] * b[i, j, 2] - a[i, j, 2] * b[i, j, 1]
            e[i, j, 1] = a[i, j, 2] * b[i, j, 0] - a[i, j, 0] * b[i, j, 2]
            e[i, j, 2] = a[i, j, 0] * b[i, j, 1] - a[i, j, 1] * b[i, j, 0]
    return e

# NOTE: avoid the slow building of temporary arrays
@njit(parallel=True)
def cross_absolute_magnitude(cross):
    return cross[:, :, 0] ** 2 + cross[:, :, 1] ** 2 + cross[:, :, 2] ** 2

# NOTE: avoid the slow building of temporary arrays again and multiple pass in memory
# Warning: do the work in-place
@njit(parallel=True)
def discard_singularities(arr):
    for i in prange(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            for k in range(3):
                if np.isinf(arr[i, j, k]) or np.isnan(arr[i, j, k]):
                    arr[i, j, k] = 0.0

@njit(parallel=True)
def compute_k(strengths, r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude, r_0_dot_r_1, r_1_length, r_0_dot_r_2, r_2_length):
    return (strengths
        / (4 * np.pi * r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude)
        * (r_0_dot_r_1 / r_1_length - r_0_dot_r_2 / r_2_length)
    )

@njit(parallel=True)
def rDotProducts(b, c):
    assert b.shape == c.shape and b.shape[2] == 3
    n, m = b.shape[0], b.shape[1]
    ab = np.empty((n, m))
    ac = np.empty((n, m))
    for i in prange(n):
        for j in range(m):
            ab[i, j] = 0.0
            ac[i, j] = 0.0
            for k in range(3):
                a = b[i, j, k] - c[i, j, k]
                ab[i, j] += a * b[i, j, k]
                ac[i, j] += a * c[i, j, k]
    return (ab, ac)

# Compute `np.sum(arr, axis=1)` in parallel.
@njit(parallel=True)
def collapseArr(arr):
    assert arr.shape[2] == 3
    n, m = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]
    res = np.empty((n, 3))
    for i in prange(n):
        res[i, 0] = np.sum(arr[i, :, 0])
        res[i, 1] = np.sum(arr[i, :, 1])
        res[i, 2] = np.sum(arr[i, :, 2])
    return res

def calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices(points, origins, terminations, strengths, collapse=True):
    r_1 = subtract(points, origins)
    r_2 = subtract(points, terminations)
    # NOTE: r_0 is computed on the fly by rDotProducts

    r_1_cross_r_2 = nb_2d_explicit_cross(r_1, r_2)

    r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude = cross_absolute_magnitude(r_1_cross_r_2)

    r_1_length = nb_2d_explicit_norm(r_1)
    r_2_length = nb_2d_explicit_norm(r_2)

    radius = 3.0e-16
    r_1_length[r_1_length < radius] = 0
    r_2_length[r_2_length < radius] = 0
    r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude[r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude < radius] = 0

    r_0_dot_r_1, r_0_dot_r_2 = rDotProducts(r_1, r_2)

    with np.errstate(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore"):
        k = compute_k(strengths, r_1_cross_r_2_absolute_magnitude, r_0_dot_r_1, r_1_length, r_0_dot_r_2, r_2_length)
        k = np.expand_dims(k, axis=2)
        induced_velocities = k * r_1_cross_r_2

    discard_singularities(induced_velocities)

    if collapse:
        induced_velocities = collapseArr(induced_velocities)

    return induced_velocities
```

On my machine, this code is **2.5 times faster** than the initial implementation on arrays of size `10**3`. It also use a bit **less memory**.

Comment: Wow, that was a massive improvement. The run time is now 156 s, which is a 29% increase. This makes sense, given that you made roughly 60% of the code 2.5 times faster! I'll add this as an update.