# Can't get improvement when using multiprocessing in AWS EC2 computer

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, cpu, python-multiprocessing

My algorithm is calculating an average over 1,000,000 separate processes, therefore uses `Pool` of `python multiprocessing` library (once I tried with map and once with `imap`)

When I a computer with 28, it did it with ~350 iterations/minute

When I moved to AWS EC2, which is with 192 CPU cores, **it improved only by a factor of 2! ~700 iterations/minute.**

I wonder if there is any good practice I am missing...?

I tried:

- monitor CPU usage - all of them seem to be used
  [image]
- Memory monitor - using only 15GB of 750GB RAM that the EC2 has
  [image]
- using `map` instead `imap` did not improve
- seems that the sweet spot is giving `Pool` parameter of 53 cores instead 192 (gives time of ~950 iter/min)

The code looks like:

```
import os

NUM_THREADS = "1"

os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = NUM_THREADS
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = NUM_THREADS
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = NUM_THREADS
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = NUM_THREADS
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = NUM_THREADS

import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def sample_in_pool(n_r_c_touple):
    # calculations using matrices, multiplications, numpy - extensive use of cpu

    return (xsyndrome, zsyndrome,
            np.array(exact_choi_matrix),
            np.array(correction_exact),
            np.array(diamond_norms))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def run_test(rows,cols,nsamples, ncores):        

        starttime = time.time()

        with Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
            result = pool.map(sample_in_pool, [(noise_pepso, rows, cols)] * nsamples)
            xsyndrome = [x[0] for x in result]
            zsyndrome = [x[1] for x in result]
            exact_choi_matrix = [x[2] for x in result]
            correction_exact = [x[3] for x in result]
            diamond_norms = [x[4] for x in result]
            pool.terminate()
            pool.close()
            samples_so_far = nsamples

        "\nSamples/min (min): " + str(round(samples_so_far / ((time.time() - starttime) / 60)))

    def run_batch_of_d_N_composite(d, composite, N,nsamples):

        for i in range(N):
            diamond_mean, plot_str = run_test(rows=d, cols=d,
                     nsamples=nsamples, ncores=ncores,
                     noise_type="Composite",
                     rot_angle=0.1,
                     composite=composite, big_omega_error=False,
                     test_batch=test_batch_folder, computer_name=computer)

    run_batch_of_d_N_composite(d=7, composite=False, N=1,nsamples=1500)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that each worker you spawn through pool has to pickle/unpickle all arguments and results passed. This takes time and is much more evident when you run alot of jobs, and the arguments are fairly complex objects, in which case the benefits will increase less and less linearly with the amount of jobs you spawn. In order to avoid extra pickling/unpickling calls, especially useful if the arguments remain same (like in `run_test`), use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684817/pickle-unpickle-only-once-per-worker) and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I was sure that the whole idea of using Pool is doing exactly this in the background, isn't it? Does it seem you recommend creating a Pool manually with N_CORES different processes?

Comment: All the work you delegate to the workers inside the pool is cpu-bound, isn't it?

Comment: If I understand you right - yes. I mean, it is separate works, each one in other CPU, the more cpus, the more parallel working of those independent tasks.

Comment: By the way, for some reason I found that the sweet spot is telling Pool to use 53 cores, I have no idea why, but it is still not giving linear improvement

Comment: I meant to ask whether the work inside you do is CPU heavy or not. For example, sorting lists is a CPU-heavy task, where it only uses the CPU. On the other hand, making http requests is not a CPU-heavy task since its waiting for input/output during which the CPU is not being used

Comment: Oh, it is cpu and memory heavy, this is a very big matrices multiplications. Every iteration needs to make multiplication of mateices in size of millions of numbers

Comment: There is only using the CPU in this simulation, nothing else

Comment: Okay, I'll write an answer to explain this better then

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **multiprocessing is known to cause scalability issues** due to the expensive *inter-process communication* (IPC). The only way to reduce this overhead is to reduce the amount of data transferred between processes (centralized slow operation) possibly by operating on **shared memory**. Multithreading can theoretically mitigate this problem but the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) of the mainstream CPython interpreter prevents any speed-up unless it is released. This is the case for many Numpy operation but it will still not scale perfectly due to theoretical limitations (see later). If your computation only make Numpy operations, I strongly advise you not to use multiprocessing but the fork-join operations of **Numba/Cython** (they use multithreading but without the GIL issue so you do not pay the cost of creating process nor IPC).

Moreover, **no computation can perfectly scale**. The ones with a slight sequential portion of sequential work does not scale well on 192 cores. This is called the [Amdahl's_law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Some resources likes the RAM is shared between cores and can be saturated (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756574) recent post for example).

Additionally, **computing machine are not a set of independent cores, they are far more complex**. Indeed, modern computing machines with a lot of cores are **NUMA systems**. On such machines, cores are grouped into NUMA nodes that can access efficiently to their own memory but less efficiently to the one of others. NUMA nodes haves their own memory that can be easily saturated if all the memory is allocated on the same node. Thus, you need to balance data on several nodes so to avoid this problem. This is done by controlling the **NUMA allocation policy**. The default policy is generally to perform a local allocation during the **first-touch** on a memory page so you need to perform local accesses. Multiprocessing tends to have a good behaviour regarding the allocation policy assuming processes do not moves between cores. Thus, you need to **bind processes to cores** so to improve data locality. Further, more physical cores contains multiple **hardware threads** sharing the same resources (so it is generally not much faster to run 2 processes on the same core if they are doing optimized numerically-intensive operations). This is called [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) and it is useful to speed up latency bound computations (eg. IO-bound codes, data transpositions, unoptimized scalar codes). This is a very complex topic. For more information please read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) and possibly high-performance computing books.

In fact, EC2 machines have 2 sockets of AMD EPYC 7R13 with 48 core each and 2 threads per cores. This is a good example of complex NUMA architecture with SMT. Thus, in practice, **you should expect only a speed up smaller than 96** (assuming the IPC does not help much which is unlikely for Numpy codes). Because Numpy perform a lot of **temporary array copies**, the code can certainly be **memory bound** and **saturate the RAM** (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750661) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431361) for example). Again, Numba/Cython can help to reduce the number of temporary array created and make the whole computation less memory-bound (and thus eventually scale better).

Comment: Thank you so much for the well-explained answer! I will try to understand how practically I can do what you suggested

Answer (score 2):

There could be many possible reasons why your code might not be performing as well as you'd want it to, but in this answer I will focus on one such area: **data serialization in multiprocessing**.

Whenever you create a pool, all the arguments need to be serialized so that they can be used with another process (also called pickling). Multiprocessing uses [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to do so. This serialization happens for **every task** that the pool creates, rather than per process. For example, consider the code below, where we subclass the builtin `str` class and override the dunder methods `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. These methods are used to tell python (and pickle) how to serialize/deserialize your object. We leave a helpful `print` statement to know what is happening when we create our pool:

```
class NewString(str):

    def __getstate__(self):
        print('being serialized')
        return self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print('being deserialized?')
        self.__dict__ = state

def worker(string):
    print(string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(2)
    string = NewString('inside worker')
    args = [string for _ in range(5)]
    time.sleep(5)
    p.map(worker, args)
```

**Output**

```
being serialized
being serialized
being serialized
being serialized
being serialized
being deserialized?
inside worker
being deserialized?
inside worker
being deserialized?
inside worker
being deserialized?
inside worker
being deserialized?
inside worker
```

As you can see, there were a total of 5 pickling, and 5 unpickling calls made, even though the number of processes the pool was started with was 2. Again, this is because the Pool class pickles these arguments per task, rather than per worker.

This obviously adds extra-overhead, which scales with the complexity of the objects that need to pickled (keep in mind the result from the worker is pickled as well). Therefore, if you are passing "big matrices, with a size in million of numbers", and creating a million tasks, these extra pickling/unpickling calls will take longer as well (more complex objects), and impact your performance.

### So what's the solution?

Ideally, we want to restrict the number of pickling calls to at most the number of worker we create (below that would be impossible). To do this, we use [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) instead of Pool (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72711821/16310741) for detailed demonstration of only pickling once per worker using process). The gist of the approach here is that instead of creating a few workers and passing them a lot of tasks using a pool, we create a few intermediatory workers using Process, and pass them the list of tasks which they can execute using the original workers in their own process, without needing to pickle/unpickle. This is made much clearer in the code below. But before that, coming back to your use-case, since the tasks are more cpu-bound, lets assume the optimal number of processes we can create is 8 (this will be different for your machine). Therefore, if we can limit the number of serialization calls to 8, then exactly how much of a difference can we expect? Let's check using the code below:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
import random
import time


def main_worker(my_list):
    new_list = random.sample(range(10000, 99999), 1000)
    return new_list

def indirect_worker(count, arg):
    t = time.time()
    results = []
    for i in range(count):
        results.append(main_worker(arg[i]))
    print(f"Process completed in : {time.time() - t}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_proc = 8
    length = 80000
    num_args = length//num_proc
    args = [random.sample(range(10000, 99999), length)] * length
    p = Pool(num_proc)

    t = time.time()
    p.map(main_worker, args)
    print(f'Pool completed in : {time.time() - t}')

    processes = []
    for i in range(8):
        # In this, i * num_args is the starting index and i * num_args + num_args is the ending index of arguments for
        # to provide to this process
        processes.append(Process(target=indirect_worker, args=(num_args, args[i * num_args:i * num_args + num_args])))
        processes[-1].start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

In this code, we first use a Pool of 8 processes to complete 80,000 tasks. The actual task is executed by `main_worker`, which just returns an arbitrary list of a 1000 numbers. An arbitrary list `my_list` is also passed to the `main_worker` as the argument. The only thing relevant about this list is that it's a fairly large list of 80,000 numbers, which was my attempt to make the data needed to be pickled larger. After the pool finishes executing it's tasks, it now uses the same argument list `args` used for the pool (a list of 80,000 lists of 80,000 numbers) to start 8 `indirect_worker`s using `multiprocessing.Process`. Each `indirect_worker` recieves of portion of `args` which it uses to start the `main_worker`. Therefore, by using the "process" setup we are only creating 8 workers, and hence only pickling/unpickling 8 times.

Here is the **result** of our test:

```
Pool completed in : 16.491206169128418
Process completed in : 10.309278726577759
Process completed in : 10.292876482009888
Process completed in : 10.574358701705933
Process completed in : 10.27439832687378
Process completed in : 10.180659055709839
Process completed in : 10.588935613632202
Process completed in : 10.58601999282837
Process completed in : 10.707130193710327
```

Now keep in mind that we had 8 processes running **concurrently**, therefore there are 8 prints for them. Assuming the processes took 11.0s (a little time should be added since starting the process itself wasn't accounted for) to start and finish, that leaves us with a straight 33% improvement in speed. **Keep in mind however, that the actual improvement will be lesser *if you're not using shared memory*, since in the `indirect_worker` we were not pickling the results to send to the main process**. With that said, this improvement was done with fairly simple objects as arguments which needed to be pickled/unpickled, and I assume it will scale as the complexity of the arguments grow. In fact, if it's feasible for your structure, you can actually use [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) with numpy in `indirect_worker` to store the return values and get even better speed benefits over pool's built in serialization of return values since you won't even have to pickle/unpickle them at all!

**Note**: I noticed this line in your code in `run_test`:

```
result = pool.map(sample_in_pool, [(noise_pepso, rows, cols)] * nsamples)
```

Even though your RAM usage isn't very high, it's probably better to use generators as the iterable rather than storing copies of the same object in memory

Comment: Why the serialization is taking so much time? I guess it is done one time at the beginning and at the end of the computation, and not while the function is running, isn't it? Anyway Thank you so much, I will try and let you know if it worked

Comment: and another comment - is a 'process.close' command is missing in your code?

Comment: I did it and unfortunately got the same speed... even a bit worse for the heavy memory option. Actually, for arguments that consume less memory ( I mean less computation per 1 iteration) your method did give an improvement of 30%. So I wonder what tells me about my bottleneck in the heavy computation case

Comment: I think there are some things that need better explaining on how to implement above. I'll edit the code when I have time and you can check whether it works for you then

Comment: @user17773618 were you waiting for the processes to join everytime?

Comment: Just as you did, first loop for p.start() second loop on each process that started with just p.join()

Comment: @user17773618, after looking at the documentation, it seems that I was reinventing the wheel. `pool.map` supports a keyword argument `chunksize`. This basically replicates what I was trying to do with the `indirect_worker`. Try setting the `chunksize` to `num_of_tasks // num_of_processes` and see if that makes a difference.